# Discrepancy in Oracle table ETL processing duration into Data Warehouse – possible reasons with data or table structure?

Tags: oracle, etl

We’ve 3 tables in our Oracle database that get ETL’d (via SSIS) into our DW environment during out-of-hours.

Table 1 contains 16million rows, 52 columns (~550k used blocks), and reportedly takes just ~6mins to load into the Data Warehouse.

In contrast, tables 2 and 3 are smaller with both containing <3million rows, ~45 columns (~200k used blocks each), but they take almost and hour each to load.

There’s no CLOB or BLOB data in any of these tables.

Data Warehouse team advises me that they’re using identical ETL packages to pull the data, and therefore suspect there must be something database-side that’s influencing this.

On the premise that tables 2 & 3 are processing non-typically slowly, is there anything from a data or table-structure I should be investigating as a possible factor in this big discrepancy between processing times?

Comment: Indexes, triggers, calculated columns in the DW on these tables?

Comment: Agree with p3consulting: the issue is most likely in the "T" or "L" and not the "E". How are you measuring *non typically slowly*? Based on what? That these tables copy more slowly than the first, or that tables 2 and 3 copy more slowly than they used to on their own? Do all three tables copy in parallel with each other, or serially? What is the system resource utilization on the source DB, in the DW, and in any other intermediary servers during the process? Is the storage media the same for all tables within the source DB and for all tables in the DW (no slower disks vs SSD, for instance)?